# Plane Geometry using Complex Numbers

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers

I am working (showly) through "Visual Complex Analysis" by Tristian Needham.

I am stuck on exercise 23 chapter 1.

Given a triangle with vertices A, B and C draw three new *equilateral* triangles on the edges of the original triangle with vertices q, p, and r.

We know from exercise 19 that the centroid of a triangle with vertices A, B, C is given by:

$1/3 (A + B + C)$

We also know from exercise 19 that the centroid of the triangle p,q,r is the same as the centroid of the triangle A,B,C.

Let x denote the centroid of the triangle A,B,p.

Let y denote the centroid of the triangle B,C,q

Let z denote the centroid of the triangle C,A,r

Show (using complex numbers) that the triangle x,y,z is equilateral

Comment: Compute $p,q,r$. For example, $A-B$ is the complex number with the same magnitude and direction as the directed segment from $B$ to $A$. You can rotate it $\pi/6$ counterclockwise, by multiplying it by $e^{\pi i/6}$. Therefore, $(A-B)e^{\pi i/6}$ has the same direction as the segment from $B$ to $r$ (assuming $r$ is the center of the equilateral triangle on the side $AB$). The number $(A-B)e^{\pi i/6}$ still has the magnitude of $A-B$. So, it needs to be scaled. The ratio between the side of an equilateral triangle and its circumradius is $\sqrt{3}$, so $(A-B)e^{\pi i/6}/\sqrt{3}$ should be...

Comment: ... a complex number with direction and magnitude equal to the directed segment from $B$ to $r$. If you want the complex number $r$, that would be $(A-B)e^{\pi i/6}/\sqrt{3}+B$. Similarly, you can compute $p$ and $q$.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still confused.... Firstly, where have you put the origin of your complex plane? At B? Secondly, my three equilateral triangles are ABp, BCq and CAr. So I assume you mean that $(A-B) e^{\pi/6}$ has the same direction as B - p. Won't it also have the same magnitude?

Comment: Ah! In my comment I called $p,q,r$ the centers of the equilateral triangles. The third vertices are not very important. The origin is not very important either. The explanation above is independent on where the origin is.

Comment: Okay, so in my notation $(A-B) e^{i\pi/6}/sqrt(3) has the same magnitude and direction as (x-B). I will think about that....

Comment: Still stuck. Thanks to your comment I have $z = e^{i\pi/6}/sqrt(3)$,
$w = e^{i\pi/}$,$(X - Y) = z(A-B) + B
$ and $(Z - X) = z(C-B) + C$.
I need to show that $(X-Y) = w(Z-X)$

Comment: I don't know you notation. But following the one I used you already have the center of one of the equilateral triangles: $(A-B)e^{\pi i/6}/\sqrt{3}+B$. The other two can be obtained just by cycling the variables $A,B,C$. So the other two centers are $(B-C)e^{\pi i/6}/\sqrt{3}+C$, and $(C-A)e^{\pi i/6}/\sqrt{3}+A$. Averaging the three, most of the terms (the parts multiplied by $e^{\pi i/6}/\sqrt{3}$) cancel and you get $(A+B+C)/3$, which is the centroid of the original triangle.

Comment: Yes, I see that. Thanks. I'm actually trying to prove that the three new centers you have found nice expressions for form an equilateral triangle.

Comment: Okay, the triangle is not equilateral, I misread the question. Thanks again!

Comment: It is ([Napoleon's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Napoleon%27s_theorem))

Comment: You're right it is. From sage: A = random() + random()*I; B = random() + random()*I; C = random() + random()*I; w = exp(i*pi/6)/sqrt(3); X = w*(A - B) + B; Y = w*(B - C) + C; Z = w*(C - A) + A; E = X - Y; F = Y - Z; numerical_approx(F.real()^2 + F.imag()^2) == numerical_approx(F.real()^2 + F.imag()^2). True. I'll think about it a bit more then I'll read the wikipedia page. It's a good question!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to deyore and wikipedia (Napolean's Theorem):

Since the triangle ABp is equilateral and x is the centroid we have (rotating clockwise around B) that:

$$ p = w x $$

where $w = \sqrt{3} e^{i\pi/6}$

Similarly, working with the triangle rBC we have (still rotating around B) that:

$C = w y$

Thus $|x - y| = |p - C|/\sqrt{3}$

Working now with the triangles pAB and rAC, and rotating this time around A we find that:

$p = w x$

and:

$C = w z$

Thus:

$$|x - z| = |p - C| / \sqrt{3} = |x - y|$$

By the symmetry of the problem we also have:

$$|y - z| = |y - z|$$

It follows that the triangle xyz is equilateral, since the three sides are of equal length.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
$\tag{Fig. 1}$
Let $\omega= e^{\frac{2\pi i}{3}}$ be a cube root of unity, then
$$1+\omega+\omega^2=0\implies \omega=-(1+\omega^2)\tag{1}$$ and $$\tag{2} -\omega^2=e^{\frac{\pi i}{3}}.$$ Since $\triangle acp$ is equilateral, a rotation around $c$ through an angle $\pi/3$ maps $p$ to $a$ and so $$-\omega^2(p-c)=a-c$$    $$\implies a -(1+\omega^2)c+\omega^2 p=0$$ $$\tag{3}\implies a+\omega c +\omega^2p=0.$$ Again, since $\triangle acp$ is equilateral, we can permute the vertices in $(3)$ (paying attention to their *counterclockwise order*) and the result will still hold. Further, since the reasoning in $(3)$ is reversible,

> **Theorem**: $z_1,z_2,z_3$, with counterclockwise order $[z_1,z_2,z_3,z_1]$, are vertices of an equilateral triangle $\iff z_1+\omega z_2 +\omega^2z_3=0.$

Hence $$G_1+\omega G_2+\omega^2G_3=\frac{1}{3}(a+c+p)+\omega\frac{1}{3}(a+q+b)+\omega^2\frac{1}{3}(b+r+c)$$ $$\tag{4}=\frac{1}{3}\big[(a+\omega q+\omega^2b)+(c+\omega b+\omega^2r)+(p+\omega a+\omega^2c)\big]=0. \qquad \square$$ **Alternatively**, from $[Ex. 19]$, we can use the fact that the centroids of $\triangle abc$ and $\triangle pqr$ coincide. Place the origin at $G$, then $$G_1+G_2+G_3=0 \tag{5}.$$ We will next show that the centroids are all an equal distance from $G$, as Figure 1 strongly suggests. Since the outer triangles are all similar, $$\frac{p-c}{a-c}=\frac{b-c}{r-c}=Re^{i\theta}=A$$ and further, from above we know $$A=-\frac{1}{\omega^2}=e^{\frac{5\pi i}{3}},$$ so that $$p-b=(a-c)A+c-(r-c)A-c=(a-r)A$$ $$\implies |p+a+c|=|p-b|=|a-r||A|=|a+p+q|.\tag{6}$$ Similarly, $|G_3|=|G_1|$ and so the centroids are all a fixed distance from $G$ and they sum to $0$. These conditions are expressed in Figure 2. Noting that the angles between the centroids are invariant under dilation and rotation, you can use the roots of unity as in  [this proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/992262/show-that-complex-numbers-are-vertices-of-equilateral-triangle/4258811#4258811) to show $\triangle G_1G_2G_3$ is equilateral. More simply, since the triangle in $[B]$ is equilateral, the angle at $G_3$ must be $\pi/3$. Imagine sliding the arrow $G_3$ up so that it is tail to tail with $G_1$, then the angle between them must now be $\pi -\pi/3=2\pi/3$ radians. Hence the angles between the vectors in $[A]$ are all $2\pi/3$ which implies $$|G_1-G_2|=|G_2-G_3|=|G_1-G_3|.\tag{7} \qquad \square$$

[image]

$\tag{Fig. 2}$