# Power of Complex Numbers in Contest Geometry

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers, soft-question, contest-math

Could someone point out some examples which very well displays the problem-solving efficiency of Complex Numbers when it come to Geometrical problems that would otherwise have a long, complex, synthetic solution? They aforementioned problem should not be a 'higher' math one, but rather from elementary Geometry, preferably from some contest.

Please try to show a comparison between the proofs in an understandable manner.

Also, if you could point out some flaws(cases where they don't work, are problematic to work with) of Complex Numbers in Geometry, I would be highly obliged.

Finally, kindly also present some sources for learning contest-level Complex Number Bashing. I know about Evan Chen, but anything else?

Thanks a lot for all solutions/opinions and advices.

Comment: a reference among many : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2773051

Comment: If what  you are looking for is complex number techniques for solving math contest geometry problems, you should emphasize that in the title and description.  Also, you don't spell out what advice was given in the first sentence.

Answer (score 1):

One of the nicest example I know deals with the internal maximal area inscribed ellipse named ["Steiner ellipse" in a triangle](http://mathafou.free.fr/pbw_en/pb425.html). This ellipse and in particular its focii can be obtained by [Marsden's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marden%27s_theorem) with proof [here](http://www.su.se/polopoly_fs/1.229312.1426783194!/menu/standard/file/marden.pdf) by reasoning on polynomial $f(z)=(z-a)(z-b)(z-c)$ where $a,b,c \in \mathbb{C}$ are the affixes of the vertices (the foci are the roots of $f'(z)=0$).

Comment: Whoa, that was awesome and overwhelming simultaneously. Though, I'd love it if some contest problem was solved, too, besides just a theorem. Thanks anyway!

Comment: see as well : https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c1090h1017278_235_proofs_of_some_geometry_problems_with_complex_numbers