# Proving Napoleon's Theorem with complex numbers

Tags: geometry

I have gotten stuck at an exercise that deals with proving Napoleon's Theorem via complex numbers.

> Consider the complex plane $\mathbb{C}$ to be identified standard Euclidean plane.
>
> a) Given two complex numbers $z_1, \ z_2$ find an expression for a third complex number that forms an equilateral triangle with them.
>
> b) Use complex numbers to show that if equilateral triangles are constructed on the sides of any triangle, then their centers form an equilateral triangle themselves.

My problem lies with b). I started my attempt as follows:
Let $z_1,z_2,z_3$ be the vertices of a triangle. Let $d=e^{i \frac{\pi}{3}}$. Let $\Delta az_1z_3, \Delta bz_2z_3, \Delta bz_2z_3$ be the equilateral triangles constructed on the sides of $\Delta z_1z_2z_3$.

We may assume that

$$ a=d(z_3-z_1)+z_1 \\
b=d(z_2-z_3)+z_3 \\
c=d(z_1-z_2)+z_2.$$

Let A, B, C denote the centers of $\Delta az_1z_3, \Delta bz_2z_3, \Delta bz_2z_3$. We have

$$A=\frac{a+z_1+z_3}{3} \\
B=\frac{b+z_2+z_3}{3} \\
C=\frac{c+z_1+z_2}{3} $$

I want to show that

$$ A-C=d(B-C)  \tag{1} $$ 
$$ B-A=d(C-A)  \tag{2} $$

as this will imply that $\Delta ABC$ is an equilateral triangle. I know that

$$a-c=d(z_3-2z_1+z_2)+z_1-z_2  \\
  b-c=d(-z_1+2z_2-z_3)+z_3-z_2 \\
     =-d(z_1-2z_2+z_3)+z_3-z_2. $$

It follows

$$ A-C=\frac{a-c+z_3-z_2}{3}                 \\
=\frac{d(z_3-2z_1+z_2)+z_1-z_2+z_3-z_2}{3}   \\
=\frac{d(z_3-2z_1+z_2)+z_1+z_3-2z_2}{3}      \\
=\frac{d(z_2-2z_1+z_3)+z_1+z_3-2z_2}{3}      \\
d(B-C)=d \frac{b-c+z_3-z_1}{3}               \\
=d \frac{-d(z_1-2z_2+z_3)+z_3-z_2+z_3-z_1}{3}\\
=d \frac{-d(z_1-2z_2+z_3)+2z_3-z_2-z_1}{3}   \\ 
=d \frac{-(d(z_1-2z_2+z_3)+z_1+z_2-2z_3)}{3} $$

But I fail to see how to proceed in order to prove (1).

Comment: Your calculation of $d(B-C)$ is off somewhere. (Compare the sign pattern with your $A-C$ calculation, and you should notice that one term is problematic.) Once you correct it, calculate $A-C-d(B-C)$. The result should factor into $(d\;\text{stuff})\cdot(z\;\text{stuff})$, and the first factor will vanish for the defined value of $d$. Note that you won't have to duplicate the effort to prove $(2)$; just showing $(1)$ tells you that $\triangle ABC$ is an isosceles triangle with a $60^\circ$ angle, which is necessarily equilateral.

Comment: In less than one minute, a Google query with keywords "Napoleon theorem complex" has given me this [proof](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/proofs/napoleon_complex2.shtml). Think to do this before asking...

Comment: [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2773051/plane-geometry-using-complex-numbers/4275486#4275486) has two different proofs of $(b)$ via complex numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simpler approach. Let's find the centroid of the equilateral triangle erected outward on the side from $z_1$ to $z_2$. We follow an altitude from the midpoint $\frac{z_1+z_2}{2}$ to the centroid,$$\frac{z_1+z_2}{2}+\frac{i}{2\sqrt{3}}(z_2-z_1)=\frac{\sqrt{3}-i}{2\sqrt{3}}z_1+\frac{\sqrt{3}+i}{2\sqrt{3}}z_2=\frac{\zeta^\ast z_1+\zeta z_2}{\sqrt{3}},\,\zeta:=\exp\frac{\pi i}{6}.$$The displacement from this centroid to the analogous one on the side from $z_2$ to $z_3$ is$$\frac{\zeta^\ast z_1+(\zeta-\zeta^\ast)z_2-\zeta z_3}{\sqrt{3}}=\frac{\zeta^{-1}z_1+iz_2+i^2\zeta z_3}{\sqrt{3}}.$$But the coefficients form a geometric progression whose common ratio is a third root of unity, so the next displacement going round all three centroids is of the same length and rotated by $2\pi/3$. And that proves the centroids are the vertices of an equilateral triangle.

Answer (score 0):

I would solve this as follows: Given $z_{1,2}$, find $z_3$ so as to form an equilateral triangle. Thus, geometrically

$$
z_3=z_2+|z_2-z_1|e^{i(2\pi/3+\alpha)}
$$

where $\alpha=\arg(z_2-z_1)$. The argument in the exponential makes the angle between $z_1,z_2,z_3$ equal to $\pi/3$.