# Prove that $IJ=IK=JK$.

Tags: contest-math, euclidean-geometry, triangles, plane-geometry

Today I have an interesting geometric problem as following:

> Let $\triangle ABC $ be an arbitrary triangle.  Points $M$ and $N$ on the side $AB$ are such that $AM=BN=\dfrac{AB}{3}$.  Points $P$ and $Q$ on the side $BC$ are such that $BP=CQ=\dfrac{BC}{3}$.  Points $R$ and $S$ on the side $CA$ are such that $CR=AS=\dfrac{CA}{3}$.  Construct equilateral triangles $IMN$, $JPQ$, and $KRS$ external to the triangle $ABC$. Prove that $\triangle IJK$ is an equilateral triangle.

[image]

I think here we can use rotation !

My first idea is to use the axe but I have problems in coordinates of points?

Can assist

I'm thankful

---

Thanks!!

Comment: If you know how to use complex numbers in geometry, then you should try to calculate complex coordiantes of $I$, $J$ and $K$ (with given coordinates of $A$, $B$ and $C$).

Comment: Another way is just to evaluate each side of triangle $IJK$ via the law of cosines (e. g. in triangle $IAK$ we have $\angle IAK=\angle BAC+60^{\circ}$, $AI=AB/\sqrt{3}$ and $AK=AC/\sqrt{3}$).

Comment: Well, actually, it's called Napoleon's theorem. See here for more details https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Napoleon%27s_theorem

Comment: @richrow can you drop an answer , coordinates of points? Please explain your other way!

Comment: For a solution of Napoleon's theorem with complex numbers see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3645355)

Comment: @Jean Marie thanks! Do you have another way ?